# How to use easymock for hashmap

Tags: java, easymock

I want a hashmap of  to return a fixed value for a given key always.

I tried the following but did not work :

```
Map<String, Integer> m = EasyMock.createNiceMock(Map.class)
EasyMock.replay(m)
m.put("someKey",expectedValue)
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong. What is the error? But indeed, I don't think you need EasyMock for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need EasyMock for create a Map with value? just initiate it

```
Map<String, Integer> m = HashMap<>(); 
m.put("someKey",expectedValue);
```